# Git save and recover

Tags: git

I just broke my codebase. I want to rollback to my last commit, but I want to save off the broken version first, so I can analyze it later. What's the best course in this situation?

(I haven't actually tried anything, just looking for some hand-holding- It's been a long day and I don't feel like screwing this up..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

Most likely the best thing for you to do is to create a separate branch to commit this broken code on, and commit to that branch.

```
git checkout -b my-broken-branch # creates a new branch called my-broken-branch
# commit as usual...
git checkout - # return to the last branch you were on
```

When you want to go back to that code, do a `git checkout my-broken-branch` to change over to that branch.

---

A quick thing you can do is `git stash`, which will save your work and you can reapply it later:

```
git stash
```

When you want to get those changes back, you can do a `git stash apply` which will apply the last changes you stashed away (but keep the information in the stash list).

As Andrew mentioned in the comments, you can also do `git stash pop`, which will apply the least stashed changes, and remove it from the stash list.

There is more you can do with stashing, since you can do multiple stashes and selectively apply them back.

Here's a more detailed explanation when you want to get more in-depth on stashing: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/10/stashing-your-changes.html

Comment: Note that typically `git stash pop` can be more useful than `apply`, since it removes the stash from the list of stashes (if it applied cleanly). This makes it easier to keep your stash index from becoming bloated.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - true, true - I wasn't too sure how much info I should throw out if this is already becoming information overload for Yarin.

Comment: Understandable. Also might as well delete your comment on the question now that you have an answer. (Oh and `git checkout -` is probably better than `git checkout master`, as it goes back to the actual previous branch)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - thanks for that, modified to `git checkout -`

Comment: Thanks guys- wanting to go branch route- but there's a 3rd step in this from what I'm understanding- I would need to do a `git reset --hard, git clean -f -x -d` after checkout to get my orig branch working..

Comment: @Yarin - if you do the branch route, you shouldn't have to reset/clean your original branch, as all the modified files would be committed to the new branch. The files will be as they were (HEAD revision) in the original branch. You can verify by executing a `git status` in the original branch after doing the branching- the changes should all be gone.

Answer (score 2):

to reset a git repo to a certian commit:

```
git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>
```

to save your current version, just commit it to the repo before you reset back to the old one

Comment: Giving a destructive command and then the instructions to save work *after* giving the command seems unwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a commit or a new branch with this broken code. After that, checkout your working code.

```
git log -1
```

Take note of the commit name (sha code - can be the first 7 chars).
Create a new branch for the broken code

```
git checkout -b broken
git add -A
git commit -m "Broken code"
```

Back to your branch and checkout your working code:

```
git checkout featureX
git checkout abc1234
```

Another way of doing this is to stash your changes and checkout your code. After that you can stash pop the files to work with them.

Comment: Why take note of the commit sha if you never use it? Also `git checkout -` will checkout the previous branch.

Comment: If you see my second block, you will see that theres a checkout for the branch and a second checkout for the commit (the short sequence of letters and numbers).